# ListView column in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have created a listview with columns

```
 <ListView Name="lstDetailTrou" Height="315" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn x:Name="Picto"  Header="Symbole" Width="80" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Picto}"/>
            <GridViewColumn x:Name="Orientation"  Header="Orientation" Width="80" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Orientation}"/>
            <GridViewColumn x:Name="Diam" Header="Diamètre" Width="80" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Diam}"/>
            <GridViewColumn x:Name="Nbr" Header="Nombre" Width="80" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Nbr}"/>
            <GridViewColumn x:Name="Long" Header="Longeur (m)" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Long}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
 </ListView
```

I fill it for a test with the code behind :
extraction is an array with data.

```
lstDetailTrou.Items.Add(
new { Orientation = extraction[0],
      Diam = extraction[1],
      Nbr = extraction[2],
      Long = extraction[3] 
    });
```

if I look the content of it into the debug : `lstDetailTrou.Items[0]`,
I see the next result: `{ Orientation = "Vertical", Diam = "5", Nbr = "1", Long = "" }`, this is correct.

I would like to retrieve into a string the content of the first column "Orientation", without having to split the result into an array and then read the fist index.

How can I retrieve the content of the column "Orientation" in once ?

Any idea ?

Comment: Do you want the first row of the column or the data from all the rows?  What data are you binding to the `ListView`?

Comment: The problem is `Items.Add`. In WPF you can use binding (bind `ListView.ItemsSource` to some `ObservableCollection<Items>` property) and add to items to that collection. Then *retrieving* data is as easy as enumerating/quering(with linq) that collection: `var result = Items.Select(item => item.Orientation).ToList();`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `dynamic` keyword and access the `Orientation` property of the anonymous type:

```
dynamic selectedItem = lstDetailTrou.Items[0];
string orientation = selectedItem.Orientation;
```